# How to retrieve password of oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g, passwords, dbconnection

I am connected to oracle 11g db through sql developer and eclipse, is there a way I can retrieve and see oracle and db password for in case I am disconnected to db?

Comment: How were you able to connect if you don't know the password?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to view or retrieve the password. If you're connected, then I would suggest you change it to something you know/remember before disconnecting.